# postgresql: no such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, deployment

I'm trying to install a postgresql database on my VPS server by using [this guide](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04).

In there it says

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev
```

And then

```
sudo su - postgres
createuser --pwprompt
exit
```

When I run `createuser --pwprompt` it asks me to create a password, once I fill it in I get the following error:

```
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

If I do `psql --version` I get `psql (PostgreSQL) 9.4beta3`

And `which psql` outputs `/usr/bin/psql`

Any idea on how to fix this problem?

**Update**

Running `pg_ctl` gives another error

```
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list'

The program 'pg_ctl' is currently not installed. To run 'pg_ctl' please ask your administrator to install the package 'postgres-xc'
```

Althgough reading up on `postgres-xc` shows quite a lot of other problems.

Comment: `psql` is a client for postgres server. `postgres` is the server itself. Use `pg_ctl` to start the server.

Comment: I've tried to run `pc_ctl` but it's giving another error. I've updated the question with it.

Comment: `pg_ctl` is a part of a regular postgres server instalation (not postgres-xc): http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-ctl.html If you do not have it - there is something wrong with your postgres installation.

Comment: No it's normal that `pg_ctl` is outside the PATH in Debian or Ubuntu. You should use `pg_ctlcluster` instead: https://wiki.debian.org/PostgreSql#pg_ctl_replacement

Comment: _psql (PostgreSQL) 9.4beta3_: how did you end up with a beta version? Presumably you're using wrong software sources. See https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt